# How to cast a char into an interger and match arms in Rust?

Tags: rust, casting

I'm learning Rust.

I'm using .to_digit() to cast a char to an integer, but I cannot match the casted value afterwards. Any help is appreciated!

```
let c: char = '2';
let to_num = c.to_digit(10);

match to_num {
    Some(2) => {println!("matched")},
    None => {},
}
```

Error: patterns `Some(0u32..=1u32)` and `Some(3u32..=std::u32::MAX)` not covered

Comment: Try this
`fn main() {
    const RADIX: u32 = 10;
    let x = "134";
    println!("{}", x.chars().map(|c| c.to_digit(RADIX).unwrap()).sum::<u32>());
}`

Comment: @AnkitJindal thanks. I saw this answer in another question. It doesn't directly answer this question though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`char::to_digit` returns `Option<u32>`, representing the digit if the conversion was successful or `None` if the conversion failed. You are matching:

- `Some(2)`, meaning a successful conversion resulting in the number 2, and
- `None`, meaning an unsuccessful conversion.

The compiler is telling you, what about all successful conversions for any numbers other than 2? (`Some(0u32..=1u32)`, `(3u32..=std::u32::MAX)`).

One way to solve this is using the underscore pattern, which matches anything. This way, you can match anything you are interested in, and then use `_` as a fallback otherwise. For example:

```rust
match to_num {
    Some(2) => println!("matched"),
    _ => (),
}
```

However, in this situation, a simple "if" statement might be a better (more canonical) choice:

```rust
if to_num == Some(2) {
    println!("matched");
}
```

Comment: ah the catcher. thank you! I was concerned with the type, didn't remember about this.

Comment: @MinhPhuongPham No problem, glad I could help. Also note that using a regular old "if" statement might be a better choice in this situation, I added that to the answer.

Comment: yes. I tried if and that works. But it bugged me why it didn't work with match ^^

Comment: You could also write `if let Some(2) = to_numer {}`